# Problem with jQuery's fade in/out in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, fade, cleartype

I already asked here with no luck, but feel free to read it:

http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/fdf7a584b30d4bb9

Hmm check out my site:

http://www.crtaci.info/

on top-right position i have search field. When you move your mouse
over there small text shows up that says:

Napredna pretraga

Now, for some reason those letters change color to like yellow for
very short period of time in ff 3.5 and to some strange color in
safari 4.0.2 for win. In ie8, opera and chrome it works just the way
it should, white letters stay white during the animation.

Any sugestions?

here is function that do this job ;)

```
$('#header_search').hover(function() {
 $('#naprednaPretraga').stop({clearQueue:true}).show().animate({"opacity" : 1},500);
}, function(){
 $('#naprednaPretraga').stop({clearQueue:true}).animate({"opacity" : 0},500,function() {
  $('#naprednaPretraga').hide();
 });
});
```

Comment: can't reproduce in FF3.5

Comment: can't reproduce in FF3.5

Comment: Dont know if it makes any difference but i am using Windows 7 x64 and i didnt test this on any other OS. On that google groups thread user Jules said "Using Vista 64 FF3.0.1 the letters change to yellow as mentioned." sooo maybe its some x64 thingy... :)

Comment: CAN reproduce on FF3.5, Vista Business 32-bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see what you're talking about.  On my machine (Vista Business 32-bit, FF3.5), it appears as though the yellowishness that is present during the fade is due to a combination of the ClearType trying to act on alpha-blended text and that you're fading white text through a blueish background.  I know white + blue != yellow, but whatever FF does under the hood when rendering the transparent text, coupled with your OS, and a bazillion other things makes it seem yellow.

When I turn ClearType off on my machine, the yellowish seems to disappear, or is at least far less noticeable than with it on.

I'm afraid that you won't be able to control that with JavaScript code, but I would perhaps try what others have suggested: keep the text visible but fade it in from a blue that matches the background to white.

Comment: I turned off ClearType on my machine and it disappear! ;) But now all text shown on my monitor is not that good looking... :) At least now i know what the problem is. Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of fixes that need to take place - This is an IE only bug that appears heavily on IE6 almost not in IE7 and slightly in IE8.

this site had some good guidelines to remove them:
[jQuery HowTo - Blogspot](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/font-cleartype-problems-with-fadein-and.html)

The gist of it, is:
- Add a matching background color to the element that receives the fade effect
- Remove the filter attribute once the element has been faded in.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a Firefox (Cairo) bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=363861 reported 3 1/2 years ago... Still ain't fixed.

Makes any text with opacity not equal to 1 or 0 get weird colored halos, not just with jQuery or JavaScript, but with CSS also. Not as noticeable with certain colors though. Seems worse with values close to 1 (.9999)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this on FF 3.5.9 with drop down menus fading out. I just added a background color to the parent container to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a background color on the actual text element will fix this.

If you have an image behind the text then create a background image for the text element that matches the far background.